# Using lodash: check if duplicate names exist between existing array of objects and input

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'd like to find out if the name that is inputted already exists in my recordset.

```
var recordset = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
}, {
    firstName: 'Richard',
    lastName: 'Smith'
}];

var data = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
};

function checkDups(data, recordset) {
    var retVal = false;

    //loop through datum in recordset
    //check datum.firstName === data.firstName && datum.lastName === data.lastName
    // if true then retVal = true;
    // else repeat until end;

    return retVal;
};
```

Expected Result should be TRUE

Comment: OK...so you have the logic. You have `lodash`. What can you use to achieve what you want?

Comment: you already have a psuedocode solution commented out, why do you need to add lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**_.some**](https://lodash.com/docs#some):

```
function checkDups(data, recordset) {
  return _.some(recordset, data);
}
```

```js
var recordset = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
}, {
    firstName: 'Richard',
    lastName: 'Smith'
}];

var data = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
};

function checkDups(data, recordset) {
    return _.some(recordset, data);
};

console.log(checkDups(data, recordset));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or, you know [some](https://lodash.com/docs#some) which is precisely why it exists.

Comment: @Vld I did not know lodash had that. Thank you.